# objective-c MKMapView center on user location

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, gps, mkmapview

I'm trying to zoom into the user location as the center reference for the screen. I have this code:

MainViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FlipsideViewController.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate> {
   MKMapView *mapView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
```

MainViewController.m

```
@implementation MainViewController
@synthesize mapView;

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc]
           initWithFrame:self.view.bounds
           ];
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
    mapView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.005;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.005;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    location.longitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    region.span = span;
    region.center = location;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
 }
```

Now I'm only getting a build warning on the last line `[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]` stating: 'local declaration of 'mapView' hides instance variable'

Answer (score 72, accepted):

When you do `mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;`, you ask it to retrieve the user location. This doesn't happen instantly. As it takes time, the map view notifies its delegate that a user location is available via the delegate method [`mapView:didUpdateUserLocation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008204-CH3-SW16). So you should adopt the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol and implement that method. You should move all your zooming-in code to this method.

**Setting the delegate**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc]
           initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 
                                    0,
                                    self.view.bounds.size.width, 
                                    self.view.bounds.size.height)
           ];
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
    mapView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
}
```

**Updated delegate method**

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)aUserLocation {
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.005;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.005;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = aUserLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    location.longitude = aUserLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    region.span = span;
    region.center = location;
    [aMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I am extremely new to objective-c so bear with me...how I do call the didUpdateUserLocation method from within the didViewLoad method?

Comment: You don't. You adopt the protocol as @Srikar pointed out and as you seem to have done and then assign yourself as its delegate like `mapView.delegate = self;`. The map view will notify you on its own when it has the necessary information.

Comment: @Deepak @Srikar - please view my original post to see what is happening now after I updated things....

Comment: @sadmicrowave Have you set the delegate?

Comment: @Deepak - you should how to set the delegate but where do I do that? I tried putting it in the viewDidLoad and in the DidUpdateUserLocation methods and I got a build error "MainViewController does not implement the MKMapViewDelegate protocol".

Comment: @Deepak - also, thats all I have in the console to show you - there is nothing else

Comment: @Deepak - like I said (check my OP for an update of the delete part also) I get an error "MainViewController does not implement the MKMapViewDelegate protocol" on this line.

Comment: Have you done this `@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate>` like Srikar said?

Comment: And one final thing the delegate method is `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation` and not the method shorthand `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:`

Comment: @Deepak - my bad - I didn't put MKMapViewDelegate inside the @interface declaration - after doing this the zoom executes successfully.  One last problem though is after implementing your last two suggestions I am now getting build warnings for location.longitute, location.latitude, and [mapView setRegion...] stating: 'location declaration of mapView hides instance variable' Do you know what this could be from?

Comment: yeah you have a property called `userLocation` and one of the arguments of the delegate method is also `userLocation`. Change the latter to `aUserLocation`. It should work.

Comment: I took the mapView off the front of mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude, etc. changing it to userLocation.coordinate.latitude and it fixed those two lines but I'm still receiving the error for [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES].

Comment: Which error are you getting? And can you update the question with your latest code?

Comment: Local variables are masking the instance variables. Adjusted the delegate method and edited it into my answer.

Answer (score 3):

In your interface you forgot to inherit `MapViewDelegate` -

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate> 
{
   MKMapView *mapView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
```

Rest seems fine.

Comment: I added your @property line and still am receiving the same problem error

Comment: I changed some stuff in my OP please check it again