# Current location button on ios MKMapView

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, mapkit

I am using MKMapView in my iOS Application. I have search bar in my view. If I search for location on map, I am putting annotation on that searched location. Now the issue is, I want to go back to my current location. I have seen Google Maps application, they have one button on Map which will send the user to current location.

How to show that button?. And how to get click event of that button?.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169919/objective-c-mkmapview-center-on-user-location

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:self.map];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**SOLUTION 1**:

Drag a *UIButton* to your *UIViewController* in the storyboard and connect it to an IBAction in the *ViewController.m*.

```
-(IBAction)zoomToUserLocation:(id)sender{
    MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;   
    mapRegion.center = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
    mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.2;
    mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.2;

    [mapView setRegion:mapRegion animated: YES];
}
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

Or you can create your button programmatically like this:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self 
       action:@selector(zoomToUserLocation)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[button setTitle:@"My Location" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[view addSubview:button];
```

with the following method:

```
-(void)zoomToUserLocation{
    MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;   
    mapRegion.center = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
    mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.2;
    mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.2;

    [mapView setRegion:mapRegion animated: YES];
}
```

Comment: This sends map to user location, but how to add the button?

Comment: @selector(zoomToUserLocation) 
remove ":" cause you don't need to send button to method as param

Answer (score 7):

Swift 3+

```
let buttonItem = MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem(mapView: mapView)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem` and pass it the `MKMapview` in the constructor, then add that button item to the navigation menu (or where ever it is your button should be).

```
(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:self.map];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem;
}
```