# Button to center view to user location using MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

Is there a dedicated button in MapKit that centers camera over user location? Or do I have to do it manually creating button and toggle `mapView.showsUserLocation = true`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6170026/3051458

Comment: @Ramesh_T have you read both questions? I don't want just to center camera over user, I want a button that does that, just like in Google/Apple Maps

Comment: @Xernox have you found any solution ?

Comment: @Xernox  ! is there such a built-in button?  (Sorry everyone misunderstood your question!)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This way runs well (Swift), and you can customize the button:

```
class YourViewController{
   ...
   @IBOutlet weak var mapView:MKMapView
   ...

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      ...
      addMapTrackingButton()
   }

   func addMapTrackingButton(){
      let image = UIImage(named: "trackme") as UIImage?
      let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
      button.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 35, 35)
      button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
      button.backgroundColor = .clearColor()
      button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourViewController.centerMapOnUserButtonClicked), forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
      self.mapView.addSubview(button)
   }

   func centerMapOnUserButtonClicked() {
      self.mapView.setUserTrackingMode( MKUserTrackingMode.Follow, animated: true)
   }
   ...
}
```

Swift 4:

```
func addMapTrackingButton(){
    let image = UIImage(named: "trackme") as UIImage?
    let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:5, y: 25), size: CGSize(width: 35, height: 35))
    button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .clear
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.centerMapOnUserButtonClicked), for:.touchUpInside)
    mapView.addSubview(button)
}

@objc func centerMapOnUserButtonClicked() {
    mapView.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.follow, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Being late, ahah, but I just found the function :

```
CLLocationManager.requestLocation()
```

So once you properly set your locationManager (with requestAlwaysAuthorization) you can call it wherever you want to center your map on your own location :)

Comment: Got error using this code,  Delegate must respond to locationManager:didFailWithError:

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the user location coordinate and set the region.

```
- (IBAction)centerMapOnUserButtonClicked:(id)sender {
MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.0001f, 0.0001f);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
    MKCoordinateRegion region = {coordinate, span};

    MKCoordinateRegion regionThatFits = [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];
    NSLog(@"Fit Region %f %f", regionThatFits.center.latitude, regionThatFits.center.longitude);

    [self.mapView setRegion:regionThatFits animated:YES];
}
```

Solution 2:

```
MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *trackButton = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:mapView];   
[trackButton setTarget:self];
[trackButton setAction:@selector(track:)];

[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:trackButton, nil] animated:YES];
```

Swift 4:

```
let trackButton = MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem.init(mapView: mapView)
trackButton.target = self
trackButton.action = #selector(ViewController.track)

toolbar.items?.append(trackButton)
```

Comment: That's not swift, but ok. So what are you saying is that I have to manually create my own button? There is no something like this: `mapView.enableButtonThatDoesCenterViewOverUser = true`.

Comment: MKMapCamera will serve as the point of view you are observing a point on a map from.

Comment: What are you talking about? I am not asking how to center view over user manually - I do know how to do it.
I am asking does MapKit provide build in button to do that, like MapKit provides little compass to change viewing direction to North.